# get the first value of some columns, in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with rows that look like this:

```
ts,ticker,m1,m5,m15,m30,h1,h2,h4,d1,high,vwap,low
2020-12-03 00:00:00.000000,DOGEUSDT,0.00336,0.00336,0.00336,0.00336,0.00336,0.00336,0.00336,0.00336,0.003366,0.0033595364,0.003356
2020-12-03 00:01:00.000000,DOGEUSDT,0.00336,0.00336,0.00336,0.00336,0.00336,0.00336,0.00336,0.00336,0.003371,0.0033696603,0.003365
2020-12-03 00:02:00.000000,DOGEUSDT,0.00337,0.00337,0.00337,0.00337,0.00337,0.00337,0.00337,0.00337,0.003376,0.0033727777,0.00337
2020-12-03 00:03:00.000000,DOGEUSDT,0.00337,0.00337,0.00337,0.00337,0.00337,0.00337,0.00337,0.00337,0.003376,0.0033747195,0.003373
```

The queries are always the same: for a specific ticker, return the aggregate data for a time range.

For that reason, in the aggregated data, the timestamp should be the first record (sorted by time), and the ticker (which is identical in all returned rows) should also be from the first row.

I have done this:

```
SELECT
    (array_agg(ts))[1] as ts,
    (array_agg(ticker))[1] as ticker,
```

And this one seems to be working too:

```
SELECT
    min(ts) as ts,
    min(ticker) as ticker,
```

Now, this will work too:

```
SELECT
    min(ts) as ts,
    min(ticker) as ticker,
FROM ...
GROUP BY ts, ticker
LIMIT 1
```

What would be the recommended way, and why?

Comment: Please show a [mre], by using _complete_  (and valid) SQL statements. (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/EVgxugOi for how they could look like).  About your question: "Why do you want/need a recommended way when the 3 options you have all produce the correct answer ?

Comment: I would like to understand the impact of each of these. There could be side effects, performance considerations, etc. that I am not aware of.
Since it is about SQL syntax, I fail to see how reproducing the sample can help

Comment: When you need/want info on the side effect, and/or performance consideration a "full **working** SQL statement"  is needed, and not "something like .... "   Also, performance only becomes an issue when there are enough records, and 4 is not enough...  Most of the details are explain in chapter 14: [Using EXPLAIN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html)

Comment: @Luuk, I definitely need to learn how to use the EXPLAIN command. I've pushed that away for too long (since DB stuff is not at the center of what I do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The all queries you wrote above return different data. To see this more clearly:

```
CREATE TABLE table5 (
    ts timestamp NULL,
    ticker text NULL,
    m1 float8 NULL
);

INSERT INTO table5 (ts, ticker, m1) VALUES('2020-12-03 00:01:00.000', 'c1', 0.00336);
INSERT INTO table5 (ts, ticker, m1) VALUES('2020-12-03 00:03:00.000', 'a1', 0.00337);
INSERT INTO table5 (ts, ticker, m1) VALUES('2020-12-03 00:02:00.000', 'b1', 0.00336);
INSERT INTO table5 (ts, ticker, m1) VALUES('2020-12-03 00:00:00.000', 'e1', 0.00337);

/*  Query 1 
This query return only first row without sorting by date 
*/
SELECT
    (array_agg(ts))[1] as ts,
    (array_agg(ticker))[1] as ticker
from table5 

Return: 
ts                     |ticker|
-----------------------+------+
2020-12-03 00:01:00.000|c1    |


/*  Query 2 
even if you add "order by ts" to this query, it still won't return you the first values of sorted date. This is return only minimum value of column ts, and same time min value of ticker column 
*/
SELECT
    min(ts) as ts,
    min(ticker) as ticker
from table5 

Return: 
ts                     |ticker|
-----------------------+------+
2020-12-03 00:00:00.000|a1    |


/*  Query 3 
this is to same as query 2, but using gropping columns 
*/
SELECT
    min(ts) as ts,
    min(ticker) as ticker
FROM table5 
GROUP BY ts, ticker
LIMIT 1

Return: 
ts                     |ticker|
-----------------------+------+
2020-12-03 00:00:00.000|e1    |
```

If you need sorted rows by date, and after then return only first values, you can use this query

```
select 
    ts, 
    ticker, 
    m1 
from table5 
order by ts 
limit 1;
```

if you need to use agregate functions then try this query:

```
select 
    first_value(ts) over (order by ts) as ts, 
    first_value(ticker) over (order by ts) as ticker, 
    first_value(m1) over (order by ts) as m1 
from table5 
limit 1;
```

These queries return same data:

```
ts                     |ticker|m1     |
-----------------------+------+-------+
2020-12-03 00:00:00.000|e1    |0.00337|
```

Comment: @thomas : This indeed explains that your first option should go, because it's not OK, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/Uq89J1kF

Comment: @Luuk, yes, I understand now. Thanks for the fiddle, it made things very clear